# update text field ui in swift ios

Tags: ios, user-interface, background, swift, textfield

i meet a question when i'm using swift of ios SDK 8

I used a callback to fetch data background and when data fetched, i want to set a text field value and update screen.

here is my code:

```
@IBOutlet var txtTest: UITextField!

@IBAction func login() {
    let username = "aaa";
    let password = "bbb";
    var res = ServiceClient.login(username, password: password){
        (res:String, error:String?) -> Void in if(error == nil){
            self.txtTest.text = res;
        }
    }
}
```

Run this code and the data is correctly fetched and the txtTest did not updated, but when i tap txtTest, the value will be shown. So is there any way to force update UI? or send a message to UI thread?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Same issue that everyone is having when wanting to do UI updates in Swift: do not ever update the UI in any secondary thread. And that means anything with closures. Since Swift is using closures so much, that issue is being seen a lot more but it isn't new.

See [Swift Update Label (with HTML content) takes 1min](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25603390/swift-update-label-with-html-content-takes-1min/25603877#25603877) for the correct way of doing things.

Answer (score 5):

UIKit is not thread-safe and should only be updated from the main thread. Downloads are done on the background thread, and you cannot update UI from there. Try:

For swift 3 and swift 4

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    self.txtTest.text = "Your text"
}
```

Related duplicate question but with specific answer

[iOS label does not update text with function in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27841228/ios-label-does-not-update-text-with-function-in-swift)